In Graphql Is removing non-nullable from field in type will keep the type backward compatible?
I have a type in GraphQl schema:
type Student {
    id: ID!
    faculty: String!
    phone: String!
    email: String!
}

And I would like to remove  ! from email and phone.
To this:
type Student {
    id: ID!
    faculty: String!
    phone: String
    email: String
}

Would this change be backward compatible, without creating new type StudentV2 ?

It depends. If your client(s) (we don't know how many there might be) have code in them that depends on those fields being there then that code will break.
A simple example: your phone numbers have a leading '+' sign for country codes but the client wants to display only the rest of the number so it does:
shortPhone = phone.substring(1)

assuming that phone is always a string.
That code can now error.

thank you for the answer, in my case the client is aware of the change,so I'll go with it.
